# How to mock the behavior of a method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I have following scenario

```
class A {   
    Response response = someFunction()
    response.doStuff()
}

class Response {    
    fun doStuff() {
        //check if response status is OK         
        //some stuff, not to be executed when in test
    }
}
```

I need to check if response is OK but not execute rest of the logic.
I am looking to achieve something like -

```
when(response.doStuff())Then(assert response is ok)
```

Can you please let me know how to do this?

Comment: I wouldn't work with `doStuff` but rather with `someFunction` and check it's response in the test method. It currently looks like your example code isn't that good to represent your actual code, because its currently unclear why you need `doStuff`.

Comment: I agree, I should be really using `someFunction`, thanks.